# How to send response code in REST services.?

Tags: rest, axis

I am developing RESTful Services to CREATE operations. In my use case, it is enough to tell the clients whether the transaction is success or fail. And if fail, we need to send them back error code.

Is it possible to send only these information back without sending xml response or JSON response. If so, how to do it.

We have existing error code in 5 digits, we wont be changing this for this api. If this is not possible.

Will JSON response better than XML response.? We are accepting XML request.
Requesting your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume this service will be called over HTTP, since that's what most people mean when they say "RESTful service."

Generally speaking, most people map "create" type functionality to `POST` methods (though you can also do it with `PUT`).

If you just need to indicate that the record was created, the answer is "None of the above" (i.e., you don't need a response body at all). Usually a `201 Created` is returned with a `Location` header which specifies the URL of the newly-created resource. In theory, you could also return a `204 No Content` since you don't need to pass anything other than the status code (though this would be more appropriate for a `PUT`, otherwise there is no way to communicate to the client the identifier of the newly-created resource).

For failures, usually a 400-series error is returned if the request message is bad (i.e., it's the client's fault) and a 500-series error is returned if a system error occurs when processing (i.e., it's the server's fault). If you need to convey additional information in the response body, consider returning a response that uses a media type of something like `application/vnd.error` which allows you to express context information about where the error occurred.

Comment: +1, nice answer. My understanding of 2xx series errors is that all of them either should have a body or they have some other special meaning, except 204, so maybe 204 is best if the OP only wants to respond with a head. Atlassian's JIRA does this a lot. 400 is a nice, general "client screwed up" response, and 500 is a nice, general "server screwed up." 400 and 500 can have a body, or not, so they're probably a good fit for a situation like this, where you're not completely sure yet if you want your service to send a body (if you change your mind, at least it's still returning the same status).

Comment: @DN: you actually should not use `204 No Content` for a `HEAD` request unless the `GET` request would return the same thing (possible but very unlikely). Usually a `204` is only returned on non-safe methods (POST, PUT, PATCH) when the resource representation is not returned.

Comment: @JW, when I wrote "wants to respond with a head," I meant a body-less response; literally, only the head. No Content-Length, no Content-Type, no body. Nothing to do with the HEAD http method.

Comment: So you meant "headers"? :)

Comment: No, I meant head... the http method, resource path, and http version are all part of the head, but are not headers. With a 204, you may not even need to send headers, only that first line.

Comment: Derp, that's all part of the request head; the response head would include a status code and possibly a reason (which are also not headers). I need to sleep.

Comment: Except that nobody calls that the request or response head; they are called message headers.

Comment: "Headers" are header fields. Quoting from RFC 2616: "HTTP header fields, which include general-header (section 4.5), request-header (section 5.3), response-header (section 6.2), and entity-header (section 7.1) fields, follow the same generic format as that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822 [9]. Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value."

Comment: These do not include the initial line or "start-line." It's incorrect to call all of this "headers." There may be an official name, but I don't know what it is. If you find out, let me know, but I assure you it's not "headers." I have only heard it referred to as "head," probably as a counterpart to "body" (or "entity-body" if you prefer).

Comment: Looking over the RFC more carefully, I don't see any part where they refer to the start-line and the headers collectively. Since they do say at one point 'header fields (also known as "headers")', it's clear that they equate the word "headers" with those fields, and including the initial line in "headers" is not correct. I don't think it's incorrect to refer to the whole thing as head; we apparently must make up a name for it if we want to talk about it, since it's not named there. If there is a more common colloquial term for that section of an http entity, I'm interested in learning it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41773/discussion-between-jonathan-w-and-dagg-nabbit)

Comment: Sorry team, i vaguely understand these answers. So i cannot send resonse with existing error code.. ?

Comment: Manoj: you can do whatever you want, but if you want to follow a RESTful architectural style implemented with HTTP, you should use the appropriate HTTP response codes. Otherwise you'll confuse people when you say it's RESTful.

Comment: By the way, there's absolutely nothing wrong with implementing something with your existing error codes. In fact, that sounds like a constraint of your design. The problem arises when you attempt to develop a "RESTful" service from a non-RESTful existing design. REST isn't a design decision; it's an architectural one. So you have to deal with a different approach to communicating status that probably doesn't make sense to your existing design.